# Oracle 11g dbca on Windows Server 2008 failing with error about services - needs some more permissions?

Tags: windows-server-2008, group-policy, oracle, service

The domain account (a slightly-reduced privilege account for managing servers) we're installing with is a member of the administrators group on the machine, but doesn't seem to have exactly the same group policy as the domain administrators, because when installing a database with dbca (specifically, when attempting to set up the services), we get:

```
Cannot open the Windows NT Service Control Manager
O/S-Error: (OS 5) Access is denied.
```

This error is identical to that from oradim -new -sid DATABASENAME

```
DIM-00014: Cannot open the Windows NT Service Control Manager.
O/S-Error: (OS 5) Access is denied.
```

We noticed that going into the services control panel with this user gives a warning, which you can continue from and then start and stop services just fine.  The same user on a Windows Server 2003 (should be same group policy) does not get any warning going into the services.

The domain administrators do not see such a warning when entering the services control panel, and they are also able to get past this error when running dbca.

Is there a specific permission which has changed with Windows Server 2008 which we need to add to our group policy or something?

Comment: What's the warning when opening services.msc?  Since the user's an admin on the system, I'd wager UAC is to blame.

Comment: @Shane - yes, it's the regular UAC warning - "Windows needs your permission to continue" - I assume this elevates permissions.

Comment: @Shane - "UAC Behavior of the elevation prompt for admins in admin approval mode", set to "elevate without prompting" stops the prompting, but this doesn't seem to affect the actual rights Oracle needs so the installation fails.  Running the installation as (local) administrator works, and we can add that to the installation script, but none of the other parts of the installation script needed that kind of thing so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running the installer with escalated permissions should do the trick - Right-click and "Run As Administrator", or set to run as admin in the Properties window under the Compatibility tab.

If this doesn't work, then it may be spinning off a separate process that is losing the permission escalation; in that case, you'll want to just disable UAC temporarily (Control Panel -> User Accounts -> Change User Account Control settings).